# Autocompletetextview custom adapter not working

Tags: android

I have an `autocompletetextview` in my main activity which i have implemented as follows:

```
String[] values = new String[]{"Linux", "Ubuntu", "iPhone", "Android", "iOS"};
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocompleteView);
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(this);
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, values));
```

I have also implemented the methods for the `TextWatcher` in the same class.

My `adapter` class looks like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, -1, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_symbol);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_company_name);
    textView1.setText(values[pos]);
    textView2.setText(values[pos]);
    return rowView;
}
}
```

And here is my `xml` code for the view:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocompleteView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activity_heading_1"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:hint="@string/autocomplete_hint" />
```

Since my values are `Linux, Ubuntu, iPhone, Android and iOS`, i expect my autocomplete to work such that when i enter `a/A`, it shows `Android`. But instead it always shows the element at position `0` i.e., it always shows `Linux`. When i type `i/I`, it should give me `iPhone and iOS`, but instead it gives me `Linux, Ubuntu`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: when i click on the element from the dropdown, the correct value gets replaced in the `view` i.e., when i type `a/A` though `linux` gets displayed in the dropdown, when i click on it, `Android` gets displayed in the `autocomplete` view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom `Filter` for your `ArrayAdapter`

Check this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/03/Android-Custom-AutoCompleteTextView-Filter.html).